# mv error in shell script "are the same file"

Tags: bash, scripts, mv

I'm trying to get a script that will rename and move videos. Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/"
dest="/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/"

for file in "$src"*.*; do
newfile="${dest}$(date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S").MOV"
mv "$file" "$newfile" 
done
```

When I debug the output, I see this:

```
$ sudo bash -v videorename.sh 

date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
mv: '/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/IMG_7662.MOV' and '/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/2016-      05-08 11 57 58.MOV' are the same file
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
mv: '/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/IMG_7687.MOV' and '/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/2016-    05-09 16 03 39.MOV' are the same file
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
```

Details of the src directory:

```
ls -lia
total 148402
1443129 drwxrwxrwx  3 chris linuxadmin        0 Oct  9 18:12 .
26870564 drwxrwxrwx 15 chris linuxadmin        0 Oct  5 15:51 ..
1441900 -rwxrwxrwx  1 chris linuxadmin 75031725 May  8 11:57 IMG_7662.MOV
1443124 -rwxrwxrwx  1 chris linuxadmin 76930641 May  9 16:03 IMG_7687.MOV
```

I've changed the contents of the source directory several times. Some files it chokes on, others work fine. I can't figure out why it's seeing certain files (all in MOV format imported form my iphone) as duplicates, especially since I'm moving files to a new directory.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `*.*` is Windows, on Linux just use `*`.

Comment: Either is acceptable, and works as far as the loop goes.  Just to verify, I changed it to just *, and I get the same error.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the problem, just a note. But you miss a dollar sign, which definitely breaks something, it must be `newfile="${dest}...`.

Comment: My bad...just a typo in the question. The actual code had the $.  Question is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, the issue revolved around how the CIFS share was mounted. It appears that the inode was possibly being cached, thereby rendering most files duplicates as the script tried to write the new file name. To resolve this, I added 'cache=none' to fstab and remounted the share. I've since run through the script several times with no issues.

While I know WHAT the issue was, I'm still not entirely sure WHY it was in issue. If anyone has insight to how this affects the CIFS mount, I'm all ears.

Comment: You can also run `sudo su; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` as a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't debug your scripts using `sudo`, ever!

The expression `"$dir"*.*` does not mean what you think. Try:

```
echo "$dir"*.*
```

To produce a list of files in `$dir`, use `find` (see `man find`):

```
find "$dir" -type f -print
```

which can be piped into your script,  or split into parameters with `xargs` (`man xargs`).

`find` and `xargs` (and `sort` and a few others) can handle filenames with spaces (`A file name.txt`) by using `NUL` `(0x00)` delimiters. Sadly, there is a mixture of commane line switches, (`-0`, `-z`, `--null`), to achieve this, see the `man` pages.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  If I comment everything else out in the loop, and add:

Comment: echo "$src"*.*, I get a list of files in that directory.  Seems it's working correctly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Also note that the script is not erring on EVERY file.  just one or two, depending on what's populated in the source dir.  So, there's something causing the error to trigger intermittently.

Comment: Another caveat....if I reboot the box, then rerun the script (without changing anything in the source or dest directories), it suddenly works.  Could there be something cached that's causing this?

Comment: Also, one more piece of info....if I remove the spaces in the new file "newfile="$(date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").MOV"", it works just fine.